# Custom JFrame class button doesn't load parameters, simple mistake?

Tags: java, class, button, jframe

I'm trying to to create a neater Jframe program so I decided to create a CustomButton class so I won't have to write out all of the button settings on the main program, but the parameters do not get changed in the custom class.

This is how I create the button in the main class:

```
    CustomButton button = new CustomButton("Hello World",2,20,5,5);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setActionCommand("id:1");

    add(button);
```

CustomButton Class:

```
package com.ezranestel.classes;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class CustomButton extends JButton{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String buttonID;



public CustomButton(String buttonText,int sizeX, int sizeY,int locationX, int locationY) {
    JButton button = new JButton(); 
    button.setName(buttonText);
    button.setSize(sizeX, sizeY);
    button.setLocation(locationX, locationY);
    System.out.println("Creating a button"+buttonText);
}
}
```

When run the console says it's creating the button (System.out), but it gets created and the size hasn't changed nor did the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your CustomButton class doesn't extend anything, it just makes a button and doesn't do anything with it.  Here's a version of your class that should work.

```
public class CustomButton extends JButton{
public CustomButton(String buttonText,int sizeX, int sizeY,int locationX, int locationY)  {
    super(buttonText);
    this.setSize(sizeX, sizeY);
    this.setLocation(locationX, locationY);
}
```

}

See at the top how the class Extends JButton?  That makes it a version of JButton and creates a valid button to do things with.  The way you have it set up, you are making a JButton without doing anything with it, completely separate from your CustomButton, so when you add a CustomButton to the frame, the JVM has no information about what to add.